# Increments for a range of numbers

Tags: python-3.x

Hello how would you go about creating an array from 0 to 10 at increments of 0.1 for example.  In matlab, you would simply type x = 0:0.1 :10, but this does not work in python.  For things like 0 to 1 at increments of 0.01, I have resorted to using numpy.linspace(0,1,101).  The 101 is from 1/0.01 plus 1.  So an easier way to this would be most helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does:

```
list(x/10 for x in range(101))
```

do what you want?

ALternatively, you could write your own special generator:

```
In [23]: def myrange(start, end, step=1):
    ...:     cur = start
    ...:     while cur < end:
    ...:         yield cur
    ...:         cur += step
    ...:
```

Though that won't work very well for floats, because floating point addition:

```
[0,
 0.1,
 0.2,
 0.30000000000000004,
 0.4,
 0.5,
 0.6,
 0.7,
 0.7999999999999999,
 0.8999999999999999,
 0.9999999999999999]
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is to use numpy's [`r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) object:

```
>>> np.r_[0:1:.1]
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

However, although this is good for interactive use, numpy's [`arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is faster and does the same thing but with more characters:

```
>>> np.arange(0, 1, .1)
array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])
```

But in reality, in both MATLAB and Python you really should be using `linspace`. There are some weird issues with floating-point numbers, and `linspace` is more accurate on both platforms.

If you want to do it in pure python, the easiest approach is a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x/10 for x in range(10)]
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
```

This is much, much slower than the numpy approaches (by about a factor of 70 compared to `arange` on my machine). Wayne's approaches are slower still:

```
>>> %timeit np.arange(0, 1000, .1)
6.16 µs ± 105 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit np.r_[0:1000:.1]
13.7 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

>>> %timeit [x/10 for x in range(10000)]
423 µs ± 7.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit list(x/10 for x in range(10000))
609 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

>>> %timeit list(myrange(0, 1000, .1))
918 µs ± 11.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```